# Sending XQuery resuest repeatedly to a BaseX database slows down over time

Tags: xquery, basex

I have a BaseX database that it has about 500.000 event nodes and I use the following select:

```
for $b in //EventList/Event[Type = 'Measurement']
let $date as xs:dateTime := xs:dateTime($b/TimeStamp)
where $date ge xs:dateTime('"+startdate+"')
  and $date le xs:dateTime('"+enddate+"')
return $b
```

The weird thing is that there is a big difference in the speed that the data are returned.
Sometimes I receive the data in 5 seconds and some times in 75 seconds for the exactly same request.

There is an external application that makes requests in a row.
I observe that when the application starts the data are returned fast.
As long as the application continues to make requests the data are returned slower.

Is there something with the connections that are not closed properly?

I use

```
final BaseXClient session = new BaseXClient("localhost", 1984, "..","..");
```

And in order to close the connection

```
session.close();
```

Comment: If you repeatedly run a query, the files might be cached in memory by the operating system. Memory I/O is _much_ faster than disk I/O. Furthermore, the Java runtime environment might have realized some execution paths are executed often and further optimized the bytecode; although the spread you described seems a little bit large for this effect. Is this the only process running on the machine, or might some other CPU or disk intensive service be interfering with your benchmarks?

Comment: Sory I think you have misunderstand the case. I didn't say that if I repeat a request it responds faster.
I said that with contiguous requests it goes slower

Comment: I indeed missed that paragraph. Is this the only request you're performing? I'm not sure whether creating new `BaseXClient`s instead of reusing them is the way to go, but I'm not familiar with the BaseX Java API, somebody else will answer soon for sure.

Comment: Ok thank you for your time!